# Flow, optional generic is given type but get property is missing in undefined error

Tags: javascript, flowtype

There is `TAction` type like this

```
export type TAction<TPayload = any> = {
  +type: string,
  payload?: TPayload
};
```

And here I give it `TPayload`

```
(
  state: TSettings,
  action: TAction<{ key: any, value: any }>
) => ({
    ...state,
    [action.payload.key]: action.payload.value
}),
```

However flow gives me error

```
Cannot get action.payload.key because property key is missing in undefined [1].
```

Comment: You've marked `payload` as maybe type (question mark) so it might be null or undefined. Either remove question mark or add checking that payload is not undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've marked `payload` as [maybe type](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/maybe/) (question mark) so it might be `null` or `undefined`. Either

remove question mark:

```
export type TAction<TPayload = any> = {
  +type: string,
  payload: TPayload
};
```

or add checking that `payload` is defined, i.e.:

```
(
  state: TSettings,
  action: TAction<{ key: any, value: any }>
) => action.payload ? ({
    ...state,
    [action.payload.key]: action.payload.value
}) : {...state},
```